# Prevent Visual Studio automatically changes the configuration platform every time Solution is opened

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Any time I open a particular solution in Visual Studio, it automatically gets changed to target Any CPU instead of x86. How can I make this stop?

If I switch it back to target x86 instead, all projects compile and run fine. But no matter how many times I save, it always gets set back to Any CPU as soon as I re-open the solution.

I am using VS 2008, .NET framework 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the following to the Debug and/or Release PropertyGroup in the .vbproj file after unloading:

```
<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
```

Comment: It is already there, for boththe Debug|x86 PropertyGroup, and for the Release|x86 PropertyGroup. It is not there for the Debug|AnyCPU or Release|AnyCPU property groups